# Why segment merge in Elasticsearch requires stopping the writes to index

Tags: elasticsearch, merge, segment

I am looking to run the optimize(ES 1.X) which is now known as forcemerge API in ES latest version. After reading some articles like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-forcemerge.html) and [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/advice-on-force-merge/100781). it seems we should run it only on read-only indices, quoting the official ES docs:

> Force merge should only be called against read-only indices. Running
>   force merge against a read-write index can cause very large segments
>   to be produced (>5Gb per segment)

But I don't understand the

1. Reason behind putting index on read-only mode before running forcemerge or optimize API.
2. As explained in above ES doc, it could cause very large segments which shouldn't be the case as what I understand is that, new updates are first written in memory which are written to segments when refresh happens, so why having write during forcemerge can produce the very large segments?

Also is there is any workaround if we don't want to put the index on read-only mode and still run force merge to expunge delete.

Let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`forcemerge` can significantly improve the performance of your queries as it allows you to merge the existing number of segments into a smaller number of segments which is more efficient for querying, as segments get searched sequentially. While merging, also all documents marked for deletion get cleaned up.

Merging happens regularly and automatically in the background as part of Elasticsearch‘s housekeeping based on a merge policy.

The tricky thing: only segments up to 5 GB are considered by the merge policy. Using the forcemerge API with the parameter that allows you to specify the number of resulting segments, you risk that the resulting segment(s) get bigger than 5GB, meaning that they will no longer be considered by future merge requests. As long as you don‘t delete or update documents there is nothing wrong about that. However, if you keep on deleting or updating documents, Lucene will mark the old version of your documents in the existing segments as deleted and write the new version of your documents into new segments. If your deleted documents reside in segments larger than 5GB, no more housekeeping is done on them, i.e. the documents marked for deletion will never get cleaned up.

By setting an index to readonly prior to doing a force-merge, you ensure that you will not end up with huge segments, containing a lot of legacy documents, which consume precious resources in memory and on disk and slow down your queries.

A `refresh` is doing something different: it‘s correct that documents you want to get indexed are first processed in memory, before getting written to disk. But the data structure that allows you to actually find a document (the „segment“) does not get created for every single document right away, as this would be highly inefficient. Segments are only created when the internal buffer gets full, or when a `refresh` occurs. By triggering a refresh you make a document immediately available for finding. Still the segment at first only lives in memory, as - again - it would be extremely inefficient to immediately sync every segment to disk right after it got created. Segments in memory get periodically synced to disk. Even if you pull the plug before a sync to disk happened you don‘t lose any information, as Elasticsearch maintains a translog that will allow Elasticsearch to „replay“ all indexing request that did not make it yet into a segment on disk.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, couldn't find this valuable piece of information in several blogs.

Comment: Glad to hear that my answer was useful. I added a comment about „refresh“ to it

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "By setting an index to readonly prior to doing a force-merge, you ensure that you will not end up with huge segments, containing a lot of legacy documents". I assume setting readonly is equivelent to "never write tot he index again" because I can't see why it matters if the index is "readonly" apart from just ensuring it's never written to. Presumably if you undo readonly after you can still have the same problem.

Comment: @Dylon: I should have been more precise in my response. That statement means that as long as an index is set to readonly, no "update" and no delete can happen (an "update" is the same as adding a document AND deleting one). A "delete" operation just marks a document as deleted, so it's still there. It's only with a subsequent merge operation that this "legacy" document gets physically wiped. If you're unlucky, and your segment is bigger than 5 GByte, then that segment will not be touched and your "legacy" documents might never ever get removed.

Comment: But they are removed if you run `forcemerge` again.

Comment: @Mitar that depends on the version of Elasticsearch. n earlier versions segments bigger than 5GB were never touched again. That's why we always taught to be careful with the `forcemerge` command, especially in combination with the parameter to control the number of segments to merge into.